# Internet speed test and throttling

Tags: internet

I am concerned that my internet was being throttled for video streaming (e.g. Netflix). Firstly, I ran the Ookla test and it gave the internet speed I have contracted with my ISP - 15 Mbps.

I then searched the web for a more reliable speed test and I found testmy.net. It gave worse results:

[image]

Yet, I wasn't convinced, because 10.4 Mbps should be enough to give me better quality than the 360p Netflix is having. Anyway, I searched for an SPECIFIC test for throttling. Came across this "internet health test" from battle for net.

From 15 Mbps to 10 Mbps to freaking 1.5 Mbps. My question is: is this really possible and not just a miss interpretation (I know Mbps is mega bits per second and might be confused with mega BYTES per second). Because a 90% loss of speed is just too much.

Comment: For me, "internet health test" reports much worse values than other tests (and also actual downloads). Browser based tests are problematic in general. You also can be sure that all these guys have an agenda. If you have the chance, go for an _iperf_ test with a public iperf server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will suggest to test this over a quality VPN connection on same ISP circuit. If the performance improves then definitely your ISP is either throttling your video packets OR using sub-optimal routing to the video site. I read that Netflix is on crusade against VPNs, so better check against a video service other than Netflix if that doesn't work. So better use a trial VPN account.

If testing has determines that ISP has a real issue, a sustainable solution might be to speak to them about it OR ditching them to a better one.

See below:

http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2014/02/netflix-slow-on-verizon-or-comcast-a-vpn-might-speed-up-that-video/1/

http://www.extremetech.com/extreme/186673-how-to-use-a-vpn-to-boost-your-netflix-performance-even-if-youre-not-a-verizon-customer